# Is there an easily accessible unique ID that relates to a single ColdFusion request?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I'm implementing a logging solution and would like an easy way to track which events occurred within the same request.  The logging function will reside in a cfc and could be fired off from the initial template, an included template, or another cfc invoked in any number of ways; though it shouldn't ever be called from within a child thread.  I would like all of these logging records to be attached to the same request ID.

This is a 'nice to have' and not a requirement, so if I need to createUUID in onRequestStart and make sure that's passed around I'm not going to bother.  But if there's something hidden in one scope or another (I didn't see anything in the request scope) that provides this functionality that I could just throw into my insert statement I think it would be a valuable addition.

Comment: _an easy way to track which events occurred within the same event_ - What type of "event" are you trying to track? The methods within the `Application.cfc` file give you the events already. Unless you are talking about something else because you later mention setting a UUID to pass around. That leads me to believe you are talking about tracking what a particular user has requested. If that is the case you can use the `session` identifiers that are already in place if/when you enable session management. It's hard to tell what you are really asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: You could use cookie.cfid & cookie.cftoken, which are provided by Coldfusion. These two cookies are used to track a user's session...

Comment: Pass around a UUID? Just set `Request.UUID` to a ID. It's there in the request so no need to pass it around. You should always be able to reference it via Request.UUID.

Comment: @Miguel-F That was a typo that somehow slipped by me, sorry.  I meant "within the same request".  It's now corrected.  A user could create multiple log records per request and make multiple requests per session, so the session tracking variables will not accomplish my goal.

Comment: @Leeish If a template invokes a cfc, and then that cfc invokes this logging cfc, I didn't think the parent template's request scope would be available in the logging cfc.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the request scope is accessible throughout the entire request. I believe it's like session, or application scope in that way. Application scope is persistent until the application resets. Session is persistent until the users session dies. Request scope is live through the entire page request, and I don't believe it matters where in the call stack it's referenced, it's truly global. I'm pretty sure because of an app I took over used the Request scope more than I liked and it was all over the place. Dan's answer here should work just fine. The scope is not limited to a cfc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a UUID in Application.cfc (or cfm) at the start of the request and reference later

```
<cffunction name="onRequestStart" output="no">
    <cfset request.requestID = createUUID() />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Apparently this was a stupid question, predicated on the assumption that the request scope did not extend into invoked cfcs.  I've tested that it does, making your solution correct, though I opted to create this requestID within the logging function to limit frequency of UUID creation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to provide "code coverage"? Where you can track that a change to functionX will impact a list of known top level request paths?

If so, I think what you want it to log the stack trace of every request. That contains the full stack of all CFC and CFM files, what line of code calls what function, with what values were passed to each function argument. My previous employer built an in-house thing to handle this. We had to move to MongoDB on the back-end to deal with the volume of data that gets collected.

You might also look into Fusion Reactor (analytics) to help give you some insight to what's going on with your code requests.

Comment: I'm specifically looking to log the details of API calls, several of which may be made in the same request.  I'd like an easy way to differentiate which calls were made from the same request.  I can easily logic it out based on the timestamp on the records (those a few ms apart from the same user are part of the same request), but that's not a good solution for reporting.